# How to find a line and add lines below it

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to find a line in `HTML` file which also contain `<` and `=` signs. Once I've found that line in the text file, I want to add the lines below it.

Comment: Definitely show what you've tried so far, as Prof Pickle suggests.  But also give us some example of what you're trying to do: a snippet of html; what kind of line you're looking for; and what you want to add below it.

Comment: tried replacing "-->" in <!--test--> with --></test> so that it becomes <!--test--></test> my plan was to replace additional lines as that would solve my issue..but whne i try to replace i see that "!" is missed out eventhough i tried replacing last two characters. out looked like <--test--></test>  you see"!" missing setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (%scriptsdir%/Mobilebranchota.html) do (
set str=%%a
IF !str!==-^> @echo off >> %scriptsdir%/Mobilebranchota1.html 
set str=!str:--^>=--^>^<test^>!
echo !str! >> %scriptsdir%/Mobilebranchota1.html
)

Comment: find this line<ul data-role="listview"  data-divider-theme="d" data-inset="false">add below lines below it

<li><a href="https://gogle.com" data-transition="slide">  
<img src="https://aa/test.png" class="ui-li-thumb" />
<h3 class="ui-li-heading">uat-3.0.363.apk</h3>
<p class="ui-li-desc">363.apk</p></a></li>

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing part:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "text=<!--test-->"
set "text=%text:-->=--></test>%"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo !text!
endlocal
```

Output:

```
<!--test--></test>
```

Please show more from your HTML file.